# Write into a log file with C#

Tags: c#, automation

I am using the JitBit Macro Recorder to create "bots" that save me a lot of time at work. This program can use the mouse and the keyboard and perform tasks by checking different if-options like "if image found on screen".

My newest "bot" is about 900 lines of commands long and I would like to make a log-file to find an error somewhere in there. Sadly, this program doesn't offer such an option, but it let's me use c# as a task. I have NO experience with c# but I thought, that this is easy to do for someone who has some experience.

If I click **execute c# code**, I get the following input field:

> Important: This code MUST contain a class named "Program" with a static method "Main"!

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

**Now I need two code templates:**

**1.** Write a message to a "bot_log.txt" located on my desktop.

```
[19.05.2016 - 12:21:09] "Checking if item with number 3 exists..."
```

*The number "3" changes with every run and is an exact paste of the clipboard.*

**2.** Add an empty line to the same file

(Everything should be added to a new line at the end of this file.)

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it." - Show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: I know, that people don't like to see that here, but I am more asking for a direct solution since I am receiving a lot of pressure from my boss right now and need to make this work as fast as possible - looking at my other posts on stackoverflow, I am usually providing a ton of information about the things I tried to make it work by myself. This is a solitary case and probably a ten-second-job for someone who is good with c#. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea how to program in C#, then you should learn it,
if you want to use code provided from answers.
And if you want to generate timestamps and stuff then it's not done within minutes and I don't think someone writes the whole code just for your fitting. Normally questions should have at least a bit of general interest.

Anyway:
This works, if you have a RichTextTbox in your program.
Just do a new event (like clicking a button) and do this inside it.
(This was posted somewhere here too or on another site, with sligh changes)

```
public static void SaveMyFile(RichTextBox rtb)
    {
        // Create a SaveFileDialog to request a path and file name to save to.
        SaveFileDialog saveLog = new SaveFileDialog();
        // Initialize the SaveFileDialog to specify the RTF extention for the file.
        saveLog.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
        saveLog.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf"; //You can do other extensions here.

        // Determine whether the user selected a file name from the saveFileDialog.
        if (saveLog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
           saveLog.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            // Save the contents of the RichTextBox into the file.
            try
            {
                rtb.SaveFile(saveLog.FileName);
            }
            catch 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error creating the file.\n Is the name correct and is enough free space on your disk\n ?");
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Logfile was saved successful.");
        }
    }
```